# Как сделать плавающий блок (position: fixed) если его родитель имеет свойство transform: scale

Tags: css, css3

Все содержимое страницы уменьшается, пропорционально изменению размера окна
(написал скрипт, которые пересчитывает `transform: scale` у `body`) и все прекрасно уменьшает, но все плавающие фиксированные окна, жестко закрепляются в определенном положении документа. ТО есть fixed ведет себя не так как должен вести.

Можно ли как то исправить с  помощью css без использования скрипта?

```css
.child {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #5fba7d;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.paren {
  height: 5000px;
}
body {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="paren">
  vrtvrtv
  <br>trvrvr
  <br>vrvrv
  <br>vrtvr
  <br>v
  <br>rfrv
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>v
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="child">
    Это плавающий блок
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: задайте fixed и уберите transform у body и увидите как себя fixed ведет.

Comment: элемент должен быть зафиксирован в определенной части окна, а не документа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953806/2881286) на аналогичный вопрос

---

[CSS Transforms spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953806/2881286) описывает данное поведение. Элементы с примененными трансформациями становятся контейнерами для внутренних элементов с фиксированной позицией. Поэтому `position:fixed` внутри элемента с какой-нибудь трансформацией больше не ведет себя как фиксированный.

Это будет работать при применении к одному элементу, т.е. элемент будет позиционирован как `fixed` и затем трансформирован.

Comment: не понял, есть ли возможность или нет, только с помощью css?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, нет, это поведение согласно спецификации. Но можно просто вынести фиксированный элемент из контейнера с трансформацией

Comment: Да это да, но заказчик попросил, чтобы все элементы на экране уменьшались пропорционально уменьшению экрана. поэтому трансформацию применил к body. точнее ее высчитывает скрипт, в зависимости от того на сколько уменьшили экран от первоначального размера. ну а за body контейнер я уже вынести не могу)) это бы решило все мои проблемы)))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, Тогда очевидно нужно скриптом и положение нужного элемента рассчитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте положение и, если нужно, размеры плавающих окон в относительных единицах, например:

```
  top: 5vw;
  left: 10vw;
  padding: 10vw;
```

Comment: только блок плавающий не стал